# org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: NoClassdefFoundError Unchecked CompileException

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I have this Exception when execution arrive to  ~.RDD() call in this exemple code:

```
enter code here
JavaRDD<String,String> row = sparkSession.read()
                                   .textFile("~~~")
                                   .javaRDD()   <--------- (Execution Error)
                                 .map(some Function);
```

**root cause:**

> org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.ExecutionError:
>   NoClassdefFoundError
>   org/codehaus/commons/compiler/UncheckedCompileException

*I have all dependencies for spark in my `pom.xm`l, I tried 2.10 & 2.11 for multiple version but I got the same Exception Please any Help*

Comment: can you add your pom.xml file ?

Comment: what are the jars you used in classpath? is your pom.xml file empty?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala i use common.compiler & spark-core_2.x & spark-streaming_2.x & spark-sql_2.x & spark-streaming_2.x & spark-network-common_2.x ..... and others for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is like this:

```
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
     <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
   <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </depenedency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
   <version>3.07</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
   <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
   <version>3.07</version>
 </dependency>`
```

But, don't use the dependencyManagement to manage janino in project, cause it won't work. The solution is to use EXLUSIONS => like this  janino-2.x.jar is not included by this way.

Comment: There are many dependencies that use janino-2x.jar like transiente dependency and ( mvn dependency:tree ) dont show this transiente dep, i have proced to use dependencyManagement in my Parent pom, and this last is the solution